# How to package a SDL2-based Linux app?

Tags: linux, distribution

I've written a small toy application using SDL2. I want to distribute it the most user-friendly way, for Linux.

- I should make a `deb` package, but then I should also make packages for other distros, which I'm not familiar. (I am also not familiar with packaging `deb`. Yet.)
- I should compile it to static, and distribute the single ELF, but there is no static version of SDL2 available, so I have to compile all the dependencies myself, which is lot of pain.
- Quick-and-dirty: release the ELF, it will run distros with SDL2 installed.

Short: what's the Linux equivalent of `setup.exe`?

Comment: I highly recommend you look into `deb`, `rpm`, Linux package repositories, and Linux packaging in general first. The Linux ecosystem is very different from Windows, although the lines are blurring a little bit as of Windows 10. I think there is some foundational knowledge you need to research on your own before asking this question.

Comment: I'm using only Linux for years, but I've just realized now, that I *never* shipped such type of software before. What's I'm afraid of that after 3-4 distro upgrade (2 years) my app will not launch due to an obsolete lib. I can install from source, but "my mom" couldn't.

Comment: As far as I know you are not restricted to dynamic linking in your software package. I have not packaged anything in years but it is more a wrapper for executing install scripts than anything. The contents of your binary are pretty much not important to the package manager.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the following projects:

- https://icculus.org/mojosetup/
- https://github.com/megastep/loki_setup
- https://github.com/probonopd/AppImageKit

The first two projects are installers that have been used to package many games.
MojoSetup's page has a list of games packaged with it, for example.

The AppImageKit's documentation has guidelines on building your binaries in such a way that they are usable on as many different distributions and as many different versions of the same distribution as possible: https://github.com/probonopd/AppImageKit/wiki/Creating-AppImages

While packaging an application to be portable, you will probably be interested in finding out about the "rpath" concept: https://www.technovelty.org/linux/exploring-origin.html

You cannot just statically link everything as it is not recommended to link statically against GNU Libc -- cannot find a relevant link at the moment.